# 404 Error on CSS files in Flask

Tags: python, html, css, flask

I'm trying to style some elements on my Flask-based web site, but for some reason my css files never get loaded.

The situation is peculiar though; the files will load fine when called from `layout.html` with the path `/static/css/`, but for some reason the page truncates the path to `/css/` on the second time around and generates a `404` error.

This is the structure of my Flask project:

```
Directory Structure:

+app
+static
    +css
        style-large.css
        style.css
        style-xlarge.css
+templates
    index.html
    layout.html
```

Snippet of `layout.html`:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>{% block doc_title %} {% endblock %}</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="" />
    <!--[if lte IE 8]><script src="css/ie/html5shiv.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/skel.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/skel-layers.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/init.js') }}"></script>


    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/skel.css') }}" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/style.css') }}" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/style-xlarge.css') }}" />
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='style.css') }}" /> -->
    <!--[if lte IE 8]><link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ie/v8.css" /><![endif]-->
</head>
```

The peculiarity is this; no matter how I change the url to the files `steyl-large.css`, `style.css`, and `style-xlarge.css`, I always get a `404` error that looks like this:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [05/Dec/2015 17:34:20] "GET /static/css/style-xlarge.css HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [05/Dec/2015 17:34:20] "GET /static/css/style.css HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [05/Dec/2015 17:34:20] "GET /css/style-large.css HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [05/Dec/2015 17:34:20] "GET /css/style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [05/Dec/2015 17:34:20] "GET /css/style-xlarge.css HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

The first two requests, the ones resulting in a `304` code work fine and render almost everything on my page, but the ones right after it don't.

I'm not sure why this is happening. I think this may be the cause of why elements on my page are not being styled, but I don't know why it is happening.

Comment: Do you set up your `static_url_path`?

Answer (score 8):

So, from your server log, the first two links to css files

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/skel.css') }}" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/style.css') }}" />
```

work correctly, as they should. In the third link

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/style-xlarge.css') }}" />
```

you have the css file name `style-xlarge.css` but in the server log is `style-large.css`. You don't have a link to `style-large.css`. 
To load all four css files you should use

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/skel.css') }}" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/style.css') }}" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/style-large.css') }}" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/style-xlarge.css') }}" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are my `user.css` and `user.html`:

```
projet-flask
   |-main.py
   |-.flaskenv
   |-application
       |-__init__.py
       |-frontend
           |-templates
               |-user.html
           |-static
               |-styles
                   |-user.css
```

In `__init_.py`:

```
app = Flask(__name__,template_folder='./frontend/templates',static_folder='./frontend/static')
```

In `user.html`:

```
<link rel= "stylesheet" type= "text/css" href= "{{ url_for('static',filename='styles/user.css') }}"/>
```